# How to make a form in centre of a page, which has a side menu bar

Tags: html, css

I created a html css page but when i am trying to add height to the form its not working, so the desire output i am expexting is to get the content of the page ie the simple form to have 100% height

```
<div class="section">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <a href="#home">Home</a>
                <a href="#news">News</a>
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                <a href="#about">About</a>
            </div>
            <div class="simpleform">
                <h1>Student Information</h1>
                <form action="#" id="result-form" class="resultform">
                    <label for="fullname">Full Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
                    <label for="result">Result</label>
                    <input type="number" name="result" id="result">
                    <label for="choosefile">Choose File</label>
                    <input type="file" name="choosefile" id="choosefile">
                    <button>submit</button>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

the ouput is like this, but i need the blue backgorund to cover the total height

Comment: the css added to the code is 
        .sidebar {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 15%;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            position: fixed;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        
                
        .simpleform {
            height: 100%;
            background: #78a7ba;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;}
        .resultform {
            width: 40%;
            height: 90%;
            background-color: grey;}

Comment: _"to have 100% height"_ - 100% of _what_, exactly? A height in percentage only works, if the parent element _has_ a height, it doesn't work when the height of the parent is in turn determined by its content.

Comment: I am unable to add the height for the form, even if i apply height it's not visible, unable to post a picture

Comment: Yes the parent element do have height in %

Comment: I wanted to have a responsive page with side navigation bar and form in between

Comment: _"Yes the parent element do have height in %"_ - and the parent of that parent ...? And so on.